# How does IDA pro generate function names?

Tags: ida, decompilation, functions, symbols, debugging-symbols

I am using IDA pro to decompile a series of applications.  These applications share a common feature and what I have found is that in each decompilation each application shares the same set of functions.  If the binary is stripped how does IDA pro work out the function names ?

The functions that I am seeing in common between the applications are all very abstract, for example `v404()`, and as far as I can work out don't come from any open source library set of functions.

Comment: Can you give some examples of the function names that you're seeing?

Comment: v404()? Hm, mine always look like `sub_<address of function>(params)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen 4 naming conventions being used:

- vNNN() when decompiling ARM binaries (i.e.: Android JNI code) - not sure how it numbers them as it doesn't seem it's related to their position or address within the binary.
- sub_HHHHHH() when decompiling x86/64 binaries (i.e.: for Windows, OSX) with the actual address on the name
- _name/__name() for functions IDA is able to identify via its FLIRT algorithm
- finally the clear names for functions it has enough information on the binaries to reverse as they were named originally.